# How to change the height of a numeric textbox input

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

Does anyone know how to change the height of a numeric textbook input with CSS? I'm finding that using simple style - height="20px" does resize the input but not the input wrapper. I tried applying the style to the parent DIV and this also doesn't work. i'm relatively new to kendo ui so i'm not hugely experienced but did not find anything useful within the documentation. Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: Setting the css `height` should work fine for a numeric `<input>`: https://jsfiddle.net/0e4ukymL/

Comment: @JeremyBlalock for a normal numeric, but not for a kendo numeric text box.

Comment: Got it. You @DontVoteMeDown, you should put that in the title, not just the tags!

Comment: @JeremyBlalock why me? I'm not the post owner.

Comment: Sorry about that :)

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this style:

```
.k-numeric-wrap input {
    height: 50px !important;
}
```

And this for fixing the decrease arrow(but I'm not sure if its a good idea to use since it uses `position: absolute`):

```
.k-numeric-wrap .k-link:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UlOlO/4).

You will have to fix the font size too.